# TransactSQL trigger to update multiple columns based on conditional AFTER UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

The problem I have on hand

A table `TAB1` with 5 columns (`id1, colA, colB, colC, id2`). The rows where id1 matches id2 are called authoritative rows. so we may have multiple rows with same id1 but only one row with id1 = id2.

Now, if there is an update or insert to the TAB1 only for "authoritative" rows, then update the other non authoritative rows with that data. if it is possible and if it is can someone, please provide a sample code of the trigger... Appreciate your help...Regards

Sample data

```
row 1(id1, cola, colb, colc, id2): 123, org1, mgr1, dept1, 999)
row 2(id1, cola, colb, colc, id2): 456, org2, mgr1, dept1, 999)
row 3(id1, cola, colb, colc, id2): 999, org3, mgr1, dept1, 999)
row 4(id1, cola, colb, colc, id2): 123, org4, mgr1, dept1, 999)
```

So in this sample data we see that row3 is the authoritative row (id1=id2). So I like to write a trigger if there is any update to this row (i.e. row3, then update all other rows (1, 2 and 4) where id2 =999 with the updated data

Comment: Can you please provide sample data.

Comment: I have added the sample data in main post

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE temp 
  (id1  INT, cola VARCHAR(50), colb VARCHAR(50), colc VARCHAR(50), id2  INT) 

insert into temp (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) values
                (124,' org1', 'mgr1', 'dept1', 333) ,
                ( 456, 'org2', 'mgr1', 'dept1', 999),
                 (999, 'org3', 'mgr1', 'dept1', 999) ,
                  (123, 'org4',' mgr1', 'dept1', 999)

CREATE TABLE inserted1 
  (id1  INT, cola VARCHAR(50), colb VARCHAR(50), colc VARCHAR(50), id2  INT)

insert into inserted1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) values
                      (999, 'org3', 'mgr1', 'dept1', 999)  

UPDATE temp 
SET    id1 = c.id1, 
       cola = c.cola, 
       colb = c.colb, 
       colc = c.colc, 
       id2 = C.id2 
FROM   (SELECT A.id1, 
               a.cola, 
               a.colb, 
               a.colc, 
               a.id2 
        FROM   inserted1 A 
               JOIN (SELECT * 
                     FROM   temp 
                     WHERE  id1 = id2) b 
                 ON a.id1 = b.id1 
                    AND a.id2 = b.id2) C 
WHERE  temp.id2 = c.id2
```

Comment: @user3726413 - If it helps u means mark it as answer :) so that it will be useful in future for some one :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want. Your requirement is a little vague but at least this is a start:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TAB1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[TAB1]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TAB1](
    [id1] [int] NULL,
    [cola] [char](4) NULL,
    [colb] [char](4) NULL,
    [colc] [char](5) NULL,
    [id2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


-- This is the trigger code
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Trigger_Name 
   ON  dbo.TAB1 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE T1
    SET 
      T1.cola = CASE WHEN UPDATE(cola) THEN I.cola ELSE T1.cola END,
      T1.colb = CASE WHEN UPDATE(colb) THEN I.colb ELSE T1.colb END,
      T1.colc = CASE WHEN UPDATE(colc) THEN I.colc ELSE T1.colc END
  FROM
    TAB1 T1 
    JOIN INSERTED I ON T1.id2 = I.Id1 AND T1.Id1 <> T1.Id2
END
GO
-- End of trigger code

-- Insert test data
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 123, 'org1', 'mgr1', 'dept1', 999) 
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 456, 'org2', 'mgr2', 'dept2', 999) 
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 999, 'org3', 'mgr3', 'dept3', 999) 
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 123, 'org4', 'mgr4', 'dept4', 999)
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 444, 'org5', 'mgr5', 'dept5', 444)
INSERT TAB1 (id1, cola, colb, colc, id2) VALUES ( 445, 'org6', 'mgr6', 'dept6', 444)

-- Before updates
SELECT * FROM dbo.TAB1 AS t

-- Test updates
UPDATE TAB1 SET colb = 'HHHH' WHERE id1 = 999
UPDATE TAB1 SET cola = 'IIII' WHERE id1 = 445

-- After updates
SELECT * FROM dbo.TAB1 AS t
```

I've updated my answer with full testing

Comment: Thanks a bunch. One concern I have is as we are updating the same table on which the trigger is defined does not the trigger gets executed after each subsequent updates meaning it would go into indefinite loop?

Comment: The condition in the join "... AND T1.Id1 <> T1.Id2" prevents recursion by not updating the row that initiated the trigger. Run the entire script and you will see that it does not go into an infinite loop. As proof add the line "PRINT trigger_nestlevel()" near the start of the trigger code and look at the messages generated. Of course, remove it for production.